# BrightCove Video Cloud SDK for windows 8 store apps and windows phone 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, brightcove

As per the link [BrightCoveVideo Cloud SDK](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/brightcove-sdks) BrightCove don't have video cloud sdk for windows 8 and windows phone 8 platform.
I want to integrate  HLS and akamai hd streaming provided by brightcove so what should I do integrate it in windows store app and windows phone 8 app.
Please suggest

1. Is it possible or not?
2. Do I get sdk for windows store apps and windows phone 8 apps.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For searching and fetching information from Brightcove (video URLs, other metadata) you can use their [Media API](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/index.html).